# MySQL Conditional IF statement in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, where-clause

I'm going nuts...cannot figure this out after a gazillion google searches. I have the following table (Net)

I'm trying to select the rows that matches owner/privacy info.

```
ID       | net       | owner        |   privacy
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1        | 1234      | bob          |   1
2        | 2345      | charles      |   1
3        | 3456      | city         |   0
4        | 4567      | public       |   0
```

If Bob is extracting rows it should go like this:
IF (owner = "bob") then select the row if privacy = 0 OR 1
ELSE select row if privacy = 0

He can extract his private row (privacy = 1) and any other row where privacy = 0

If've tried this but doesn't give any result:

```
SELECT * FROM `Net` WHERE IF (STRCMP(owner, 'bob'), 'privacy < 2', 'privacy = 0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `or` boolean operator to simplify this logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  (owner = 'bob' AND (privacy IN (0, 1)) OR privacy = 0
```

Assuming that `privacy` can ever only be 0 or 1, if the owner is `bob`, you could just omit the privacy `and` branch altogether:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  owner = 'bob' OR privacy = 0
```

Comment: DUH! You are right! I don't need IF statement. Thank you!